# Getting user input for scraped page in selenium in Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using Selenium to scrape content of some pages which are protected by SMS Code. I would like to build solution which would prompt a user to enter SMS code while scraping the page. If I look through Selenium documentation -https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/js_alerts_prompts_and_confirmations/

```
//Click the link to activate the alert
await driver.findElement(By.linkText('See an example alert')).click();

// Wait for the alert to be displayed
await driver.wait(until.alertIsPresent());

// Store the alert in a variable
let alert = await driver.switchTo().alert();

//Store the alert text in a variable
let alertText = await alert.getText();

//Press the OK button
await alert.accept();

// Note: To use await, the above code should be inside an async function
```

... it seems it needs the the link to alert form present on the webpage. This is not the behaviour I am interested. I need to show independent form, take the user input and continue with the automation. Help appreciated. I am using node.js so I could use console with readline module, but it seems like less elegant approach.

Comment: you can execute script to open the alert and return the value.  No need to use Selenium at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? How do I execute script from Node.js other than using web driver? Bare in mind I am in the open session after executing few steps in web driver (go to address, "sendkeys" for login name and password, click the button and then I am on a page to enter SMS code. I want to pause in this moment, throw an alert for user to input, and use this input to inject in a proper sms entry form and proceed with automation.

Comment: not familiar with node, beyond npm... I figured you could... you could use the driver's execute script command.  It will return the value so no need to use alert.getText or switch the driver to it.  You might also consider using java instead to provide a user interface.  OR launch a browser for the interface that connects to your node server?